# How to optimize slow query

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a query that fetches and constructs a JSON array. The problem is that it takes a considerable amount of time load. In PGAdmin, it takes about ~18s for only 2 records.

Any help and pointers to optimize this will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Below is the query and the tables

QUERY

```
SELECT s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name, JSON_AGG( JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
    'scoreKey', rs.score_key,
    'label', rs.label,
    'denominator', rs.denominator,
    'numerator', rs.numerator
) ) AS scores
FROM students s
INNER JOIN raw_scores rs ON s.id = rs.student_id
WHERE s.school_id = 1
GROUP BY s.id, s.first_name, s.middle_name, s.last_name
ORDER BY s.first_name, s.last_name ASC
```

RESULT

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id         | first_name | last_name | scores
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | Jane       | Doe       | [{"scoreKey": "classScore", "label": "Week 1", "denominator": 20.00, "numerator": 18.00}, {"scoreKey": "classScore", "label": "Week 2", "denominator": 20.00, "numerator": 19.00}, {"scoreKey": "classScore", "label": "Week 3", "denominator": 20.00, "numerator": 20.00}]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2          | John       | Doe       | [{"scoreKey": "classScore", "label": "Week 1", "denominator": 20.00, "numerator": 18.00}, {"scoreKey": "classScore", "label": "Week 2", "denominator": 20.00, "numerator": 19.00}, {"scoreKey": "classScore", "label": "Week 3", "denominator": 20.00, "numerator": 20.00}]
```

TABLES

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS raw_scores
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('raw_scores_id_seq'::regclass),
    student_id bigint,
    school_id bigint,
    numerator numeric(4,2),
    denominator numeric(4,2),
    score_key character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    label character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('students_id_seq'::regclass),
    first_name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    middle_name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    last_name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL
    ...
)
```

EXPLAIN PLAN
[image]

Comment: Please show the `EXPLAIN` plan. Do any of your tables have indexes, if so please show.

Comment: You've truncated the most important parts of the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` outputs: the indexes. Please include the full output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE raw_scores` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE students` in your question.

Comment: I've added an image of the `EXPLAIN` plan

Comment: Please use explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings), and post the results in plain text.

Comment: By the way, the query plan that you did show us, is from a different query and it using a different data source: foreign scan points to a foreign table. And that could be anything anywhere. Without the complete DDL and execution plan, we can't help you

Comment: @WillemRenzema `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is not valid syntax for PostgreSQL.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, You are right. I forgot to mention the `students` table is a foreign table. It's accessed via Foreign Data Wrappers (FDW) but I didn't think it would be significant. Also, the original query has `AND DATE(rs.created_date) = DATE(now() - INTERVAL '1 day')` and `s.reference_id` which I removed from my post to make it a bit more concise.

Comment: It is significant, so please update your question with the complete DDL including the setup of the foreign table and foreign server and the DDL on the other server, where the real data is stored. And always use `explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for a query plan, because that gives you details including timing.